# How to use one L.Shapefile/zip file Object but change the onEachFeature for each layer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, shapefile

The current problem I am experiencing is that i have multiple tileLayers that contain a shape file. Each tile layer represents a different data-set based on some variable and changes the colors accordingly.

I can get this to work if I create three separate Objects(L.shapefile("", {})...) and place each into it's corresponding layer. The problem is that my shapefile is fairly large at 12MB. When I do it this way it downloads the file 3 times.

How would I go about downloading the zip file once, then creating 3 instances from that download?

````
    shpfile = new L.Shapefile('/mydata/shpfile.zip', {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            console.log(feature, layer)
            if (feature.properties) {
                var data_name = feature.properties.Name;
                val = -1
                if (data)
                    val = data[days+'DAY']
                if (val==-1)
                    val="No Data";
                var tooltip_Html = data_name + "<hr>" + days + " " + val;
                layer.bindPopup(tooltip_Html, {
                    maxHeight: 200
                });
                layer.prop = {data_name , days};
                layer.setStyle({fillColor : getColor(val), 
                                color: "black",
                                weight: 1,
                                opacity: 1,
                                fillOpacity: 0.3
                                });
                layer.on("click", layerClick);
                if (vw>768) {
                    layer.on("mouseover", function () {
                            info.update(layer.prop);
                            layer.bindTooltip('<b>'+layer.prop.loc + '</b> Name<br>' + layer.prop.val);
                    });
                    layer.on("mouseout", function () {
                        info.update();
                    });
                }
            }
        }});

    shpfile.once("data:loaded", function() {
        console.log("Shape File Downloaded! "+ days + ' days');
      /* Tried this method of creating oneachfeature dynamically 
shpfile.onEachFeature(function(feature, layer) {
            var layerName;
        });

        */
    });
    L.tileLayer(mapboxUrl, {id: 'mapbox.streets', attribution: mbAttr}).addTo(shpfile)```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me quote the [Leaflet.shapefile readme](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile):

> usage:
>
> ```
> new L.Shapefile(arrayBuffer or url[,options][,importUrl]);
>
> L.shapefile(arrayBuffer or url[,options][,importUrl]);
> ```

So one can provide either the URL to a shapefile, *or* an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) with the contents of the zipped shapefile.

So now the question is: how to create an `arrayBuffer` of an external file? There are several approaches, but I'm partial to the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and the [`Response.arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer) functionality, e.g.

```
fetch(url)
  .then(function(response){
    return response.arrayBuffer();
}).then(function(buf){
  L.shapefile(buf, options1).addTo(map);
  L.shapefile(buf, options2).addTo(map);
  L.shapefile(buf, options3).addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: Excellent! I saw the arrayBuffer option in the readme, but I wasn't sure if it was for a different source and could be used with a zip file. You confirmed this for me. Thank you!